# Splunk rewrites xml input incorrectly

Tags: log4j, splunk

I have a number of applications that I want to log to Splunk. I will be sending the data in an XML format via a UDP listener. The data that is being sent looks like:

```
<log4j:event logger="ASP.global_asax" level="INFO" timestamp="1303830487907" thread="15">
  <log4j:message>New session started</log4j:message>
  <log4j:properties>
    <log4j:data name="log4japp" value="4ef113dd-9-129483040292873753(4644)" />
    <log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="W7-SUN-JSTANTON" />
  </log4j:properties>
</log4j:event>
```

However when it is processed by Splunk it appears like:

```
Apr 26 16:18:09 127.0.0.1 <log4j:message>New session started</log4j:message><log4j:properties><log4j:data name="log4japp" value="4ef113dd-9-129483040292873753(4644)"/><log4j:data name="log4jmachinename" value="W7-SUN-JSTANTON"/></log4j:properties></log4j:event>
```

Basically it looks like Splunk looks like it has overwritten the opening node, and as a result lossing the log level data, with the datetime that it received it. The applications that are sending it are using nLog with a log4j type target (with an Log4JXmlEventLayout layout). I have configured the sourcetype as log4jxml (custom name) but I think I need to tell it not to do something with the date/time field in the props.conf file (but not too sure what that something is).

I am also using the windows version of Splunk so the file paths are slightly different to the online manuals.

Any help would be most welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out I was doing 2 things wrong (maybe more but I have not found thoses yet)
In the **inputs.conf** file I need to add the following to my input definition:

```
no_priority_stripping = true
no_appending_timestamp = true
```

The second thing I was doing wrong was to put these files in

```
C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\system\local\
```

when they SHOULD have been put in

```
C:\Program Files\Splunk\etc\apps\search\local\
```

I hope that this helps somebody else out